# AsyncTask for loading photo from facebook - always return null

Tags: android, android-asynctask, kotlin, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I am using `AsyncTask` to load photo from Facebook.
The main problem is that `bitmapProf` (class `AsyncTaskLoadPhoto` , method - `doInBackground`) always return `null`.
I used debugger and Log for search error but error was not found.

Here is my code:

```
  private lateinit var imgProfile: ImageView

  override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    .....
    loadImg()
    }
  }

  fun loadImg() {
    var loadPhoto = AsyncTaskLoadPhoto()
    var bitmap: Bitmap?
    loadPhoto.execute()
    bitmap = loadPhoto.get()
    Log.i("TAG", bitmap.toString())
    imgProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap)
 }

}

class AsyncTaskLoadPhoto : AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap?>() {

 override fun doInBackground(vararg p0: Void): Bitmap? {
    var bitmapProf: Bitmap? = null
    try {
      val stringURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+"userID"+"/picture?width=150&width=150"
      val imgURL = URL(stringURL)
      val connection: HttpURLConnection = imgURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
      connection.doInput = true
      connection.connect()
      val inputStream = connection.inputStream
      bitmapProf = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream)
    } catch (e: Exception) {
      e.printStackTrace()
     }
    return bitmapProf
 }
```

Comment: I am not sure about kotlin but for java you cannot use asynctask for web calls any more

Answer (score 0):

```
} catch (e: Exception) {
  e.printStackTrace()
 }
```

You are swallowing the exception without even a log statement. `e.printStackTrace()` has no visible effect in Android. Then your method returns `null`.

---

For reference, if you adopted Kotlin coroutines, this is how simple your code would become:

```
class MyActivity : Activity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        launch(UI) {
            try {
                imgProfile.setImageBitmap(loadImg())
            } catch (e: Exception) {
                // handle it here
            }
        }
    }

    private suspend fun loadImg(): Bitmap = withContext(CommonPool) {
        val stringURL = "http://graph.facebook.com/userID/picture?width=150&width=150"
        val imgURL = URL(stringURL)
        val connection = imgURL.openConnection() as HttpURLConnection
        connection.connect()
        BitmapFactory.decodeStream(connection.inputStream)
    }
}
```

This code isn't clean yet, you must check the `connection.responseCode` to see if the input stream contains the image data or just some error message.

Answer (score -1):

Try this code:

```
ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(imgurl, image_propertypic, new ImageLoadingListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingFailed(String imageUri, View view, FailReason failReason) {

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                            image_propertypic.setImageBitmap(loadedImage);
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onLoadingCancelled(String imageUri, View view) {

                        }
                    });
```